# Função que retorne a resolução da tela

Tags: java, android

Preciso de uma função Java que retorne a resolução do meu dispositivo Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar desta forma à partir da API 13:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/ScreenResolutionAndroid.java).

Para as versões anteriores:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/ScreenResolutionAndroid2.java).

Você precisa estar em uma `Activity` para usar desta forma, mas provavelmente está. Se não estiver o código precisará ser mudado para pegar o contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `DisplayMetrics`:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int widht = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Nota: o `heightPixels` retorna o tamanho total de sua tela junto com sua status bar. Caso você queira ignorar o tamanho da status bar (útil para operações de animações etc), você simplesmente:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```