# Como pegar o tamanho do celular que a aplicação está rodando

Tags: android

Estou precisando pegar o tamanho do celular que a minha aplicação está rodando , para tentar usar isto

```
bm.createScaledBitmap(bm,200,200,true);
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49603/4337).

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, pra mim é duplicata, essa aqui pode fechar.

Comment: pode fechar então